# jQuery $.ajax calls executing synchronously instead of concurrently on calls to WCF service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a web application that contains a page with a form that has hundreds of fields on it. Changing any of the fields fires a jQuery $.ajax call back to the server to determine if any other fields need to be added to the form based on it's new value. In other words, it checks to see if any dependent fields need to be added to the form when one field changes.

There is a bit of complexity around this process and as a result, sometimes these checks can take a few seconds.

The problem is, if one field is in the middle of its $.ajax call, and I attempt to change another field while waiting for the first one to complete, the UI gets blocked and I can't do anything on the page until the first call completes. It's like the UI can only handle one $.ajax call at a time. Here's a copy of the $.ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processdata: true,
        success: serviceSuccess,
        error: serviceFailed
    });
```

The `serviceSuccess` callback has a lot of complex code to update the UI, but I deleted ALL of the code within it and the problem still occurs. I figured it wasn't anything to do with the callback since it seems to happen before the call completes, but just to be sure, I gave it a shot.

Has anyone heard of anything like this before with jQuery $.ajax?

**EDIT:** I noticed the size of the response coming back from the $.ajax call is about 130k.

**Edit 2:** The $.ajax calls are making calls to a WCF service. The class definition now looks like this:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ReviewDataService : IReviewDataService, IReadOnlySessionState
```

**SOLUTION:** So Jason definitely pointed me in the right direction. My problem was, in fact, due to ASP.NET session locking. In order to get around this, I had to eliminate the use of Session from anywhere in the call stack on calls that originated from my WCF service. Additionally, I set AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode to AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.NotAllowed and I set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" in the serviceHostingEnvironment element in web.config.

This caused WCF to throw errors when an attempt was made to access Session and I juts refactored each of those instances so that they didn't rely on session. After that, my WCF calls started running concurrently instead of synchronously.

Comment: Seems like a lot of data. What does it comprise?

Comment: It is a lot, it's the rendered HTML for any of the dependent fields that need to be inserted into the DOM based on the changed field. This is (unfortunately) an ASP.NET web forms application and we have to render the controls on the server side and inject the rendered HTML back into the DOM via these jQuery calls. In this case, there are 697 dependent fields checked (although not all of those were rendered).

Comment: I assume you cannot make synchronous calls? It still seems like an awful lot of HTML. I guess there must be large drop down lists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET they use read/write locks on the Session object.  This makes AJAX request serial.

In ASP.NET you can have IHttpHandlers that implement IReadOnlySessionState which will not place the read/write lock on Session.  Not sure what environment you are using though.

**Edit 1**

This post seems to indicate that WCF services don't allow you the flexibility to unlock the session:

[How to force an IIS hosted WCF or ASMX [webservice] to use session object readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269198/how-to-force-an-iis-hosted-wcf-or-asmx-webservice-to-use-session-object-readon)

**Edit 2**

Setting up an IHttpHandler that will not lock the Session object.

*Web.config*

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="MyProvider" path="MyProvider.aspx" verb="*" type="MyNamespace.MyProvider" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

*MyProvider.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyProvider : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to create a provider that receives and returns JSON objects you can create classes for the Request and Response and then your handler can be set up like this:

*MyProvider.cs (processing JSON objects)*

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace TestWebsite
{
    public class MyProvider : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var response = new Json.Response();
            try
            {
                var requestSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Json.Request));
                var request = (Json.Request)requestSerializer.ReadObject(context.Request.InputStream);

                // ...
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.Error = ex.ToString();
            }

            try
            {
                var responseSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Json.Response));
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                responseSerializer.WriteObject(context.Response.OutputStream, response);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an ASP.NET application. I'd have to sort through all of the calls to see if we're hitting Session during any of them. Worth looking into though.

Comment: You don't actually have to be using Session.  ASP.NET will by default lock the session.  Try implementing the IReadOnlySessionState on your web service and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I was kind of hopeful on this one, but implementing IReadOnlySessionState on the web service didn't have any effect. It still sounds like this has potential though, I'll check it out a little more.

Comment: Are you calling an .ASMX, .APSX, custom IHttpHandler, etc?  All of our AJAX calls are to a custom IHttpHandler that acts specifically as an Ajax Provider.  I haven't tried making ASPX or ASMX pages use IReadOnlySessionState so I'm can't assert exactly how that works.  I can provide an example of setting up an IHttpHandler if that would help.

Comment: I haven't quite solved the problem yet, but your answer has given me a really good starting place on this, so I'll mark it as the answer. When I resolve the issue, I'll update my post with the solution. Thanks for the help.