# IIS Server waiting on a Service call instead of serving the next request

Tags: asp.net, ajax, xmlhttprequest, iis-8, http-redirect

I have an ASP.Net web application with a page Home.aspx showing some statistics. 
[image: Home Page Request]The Home page has a JQuery Ajax request to load the dashboard statistics from the server. The calculating takes a few seconds and the UI is showing the loading animation. The user decides to move to a different page say HelpDesk.aspx and the request will not be served until the JQUERY AJAX request is returned. [image: XHR Request and next page request] The Page HelpDesk.aspx is a static page and no logic involved hence would expect a quick response whereas the server has waited (unless the browser tools are fooling me) on the “GetDashboardStatistics” AJAX request before sending the response for the HelpDesk.aspx page.[image: HomePageCode].
Webservice code would be as follows

```
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://XYZ/XYZService")]
        [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
        public class XYZService{

        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",  RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public DashboardStatisticsDTO[] GetDashboardStatistics(DashboardStatisticsRequestDTO dashboardStatisticsRequest)
        {
            var list = new List<DashboardStatisticsDTO>();
//Use Session Information to identify the user
                   //business logic to load the entity collection
             return list.ToArray();
        }

        }
```

What I need: Is there a way I can straight away force the redirection instead of waiting on the server to complete and return response? I.e. User clicks on Home which shows loading animation and decides to navigate away before response is returned from server, How to achieve this?

Comment: Abort the request. If user clicks a link during request there isn't any reason it shouldn't get aborted automatically by browser anyway. User interaction isn't held up by active requests

Comment: ASP.NET has its async support which you should explore. Your current approach might be in sync (you show no code though), which means the thread pool can be exhausted easily if such service calls are too many.

Comment: To Charlie: Even I have expected the browser to abort the current ajax call that its waiting on and initiate the page redirection. you could see from second image that browser did place next request to server between 2-3seconds (1 sec after AJax request was placed). But some reason IIS chose to respond after completing the first ajax request.

Comment: To Lex: I am limited by framework to tap into the ASYNC option and my test scenario does not have any restriction on Threadpool as i have ensured no other request is placed onto the sandbox instance. And i presume thread pool wont just exhausted by single page request (multiple resource of course).Is there any thing IIS does to uniquely identify and stack requests (against the stateless web nature i guess)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is same as AJAX calls gets blocked whenever the WCF service has to use Context information into the picture.

Finally, I have used the following code in my **Global.asx.cs** to solve the issue.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (Request != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Path))
        {
            if (Request.Path.Contains(@".svc/"))
            {
                Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
            }
        }
    }
```

Extensive search for this issue found that there are similar questions already posted and a few of the are:
[Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269198/how-to-force-an-iis-hosted-wcf-or-asmx-webservice-to-use-session-object-readon) |
[Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742211/ajax-accessible-long-running-service-tasks-blocking-sub-sequent-ajax-service-req) 
and MSDN Blog:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlightws/archive/2009/09/30/having-a-pollingduplex-service-and-any-other-wcf-service-in-the-same-website-causes-silverlight-calls-to-be-slow.aspx